# 148-to-141 conversion effect on spoke length?

Tags: wheels, spokes, wheel-building

I'm building a set of wheels using:

- WTB KOM Light i40 rims - 27.5"
- Hope Pro 4 Hubs - 100mm front / 148mm rear

However, I have converted the rear hub to a 141mm using Hope's QR conversion kit.

**Does this change have an effect on the spoke length calculation?**

I have used the [DT Swiss spoke calculator](https://spokes-calculator.dtswiss.com/en/calculator) with the values from WTB and Hope for [ERD](https://www.wtb.com/products/kom-light), and [PCD/offset](https://www.hopetech.com/_repository/1/documents/2016UPDATEDHOPEHUBSSPOKEOFFSETANDPCD_v2.pdf). But I'm unsure if the PCD/offset values are changed by the conversion to 141.

Comment: Try poking your measurements into http://wheelspoking.com/Build.aspx and see the results.   I expect none of the critical measurements to change because of your kit.

Answer (score 2):

The PCD of the hub flanges cannot be changed. but the flange offsets might be. What might happen is the hub body is shifted left or right relative to the centerline by the axle conversion.

The offsets are easy to measure, a millimeter scale ruler gives sufficient accuracy. Try this page: https://leonard.io/edd/howtomeasure. I'd personally check the published measurements anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The QR conversion does not affect spoke length.

PCD is determined by the hub only, and offset would be changed only if the hub end caps were different size on each side.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion kit "shouldn't" change the dish of the rear wheel.  The rim should be centered between the locknuts (aka the ends of the axle which contact the frame).

If you don't have a dish tool, take the wheel to a LBS and have them check the dish. This should only take a few minutes and most shops will do this for nominal charge.

Should the wheel needs to be re-dished, there should be ample margin with the factory spokes to move the rim.  When I've had to adjust the dish of rims which were off by a couple mm it simply was a turn or two difference to the spokes on each side (i.e. loosen one side by a turn and tighten the other side a turn).

Only if the conversion kit significantly changed the dish of the wheel would you need to change any spoke lengths. Hope makes excellent stuff so if there is a major change to the dish, I would contact Hope for technical assistance as there likely is another problem (wrong kit, missing part, etc etc).